# Alias for variables in pattern matching

Tags: ocaml

I often have something similar to the following (standard type definition for trees):

```
match tree with
    | Branch(v, Branch(vl, tll, tlr), _) = f Branch(vl, tll, tlr)
```

In other languages there is the ability to do something like:

```
match tree with
    | Branch(v, tl@Branch(_, _, _), _) = f tl
```

Does OCaml have something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done using the `as` keyword in OCaml:

```
match tree with
| Branch(v, (Branch(_, _, _) as tl), _) = f tl
```

Comment: This is failing to compile for me, although it works if I surround the `Branch(_,_,_) as tl` in parenthesis

Comment: @Cjen1 Right, my mistake. Without the parentheses it take `v, Branch(_,_,_)` to be the left operand of `as`.